# Form Component inheriting CommonDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, components

well, as the title says, I need to create a component inheriting from the commonDialog. I have a form already created and working, but I need to create it as a component (like OpenFileDialog) to use in later project (like a "pop-up").

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CommonDialog is a very specific base class that was designed to act as a common base class for dialogs that are built into Windows.  It is not an appropriate base class for your own component.  Simply derive from Component instead.

A simple example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyComponent : Component {

    public bool ShowDialog() {
        using (var dlg = new WindowsFormsApplication1.Form2()) {
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                // Retrieve properties
                //...
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }

    // Add your own properties here
    //...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this code works even if my form is just a normal form (I mean, the one we create as a project) ? Because I don't think that my Form will have the ShowDialog() property.

Comment: Every form has the ShowDialog() method.  And sure, you might as well use your form without wrapping it in a Component if the form is already part of your project.  The only point of making it a component is to have it on the toolbox.  Like OpenFormDialog.

Comment: Exactly, thats the point, so I can reuse it later on ! Thanks, I'll give it a try and post results tomorrow !