# How to get image/icon below form designer for my custom component when added on form in design mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, components, custom-component

I am using Visual Studio 2010, C# and WinForms and have created custom component like this:

```
public partial class SlidePanel : Panel 
{
    some code here...
}
```

So it is a component class not a user control.

What I want is when I drag my component on the windows form to get an icon representing my component below the form. An example would be the existing binding source control - when you add it to form it gives you an icon below the form (on form designer) which you can select and then change properties. How can I do this? The icon can be a generic one.

Comment: A Panel is a control, not a component.

Comment: Ok,so can i do it with control ?

Comment: Inherit from component instead of Panel.  But I'm guessing that's not what you really want.  If there are so many things on your form that you can't find them in design view, then you have too many things on your form.  Find ways to reduce a cluttered form, your users will appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks for you effort, I m doing this for myself. So no other people working on this. So basically i  made a panel that can extend and shrink(timer for magic) and i don't have so many controls on form(i can find it), but i can see it can be done(by binding source control, telerik thema control) and i wana learn,know how to be done. I have a strong feeling that it's not hard. I have google it, but don't know what to search. "user control image/icon shown below form designer" didn't help :(

Comment: Inherit from component did the trick, you see i was right it was easy :). Thank you. Now i how to figure it out how to combine component and panel :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So it is a component class not a user control.

No, it is neither.  It's still a panel control, you just customized its behavior.  If this class is in a project in your solution then you'll automatically get it added to the toolbox after you compile.  At the top, right after the arrow.  If that doesn't happen then you have a setting wrong.  Tools + Options, Windows Forms Designer, General, ensure that AutoToolboxPopulate is set to True.

If you actually want what you describe (icon added at bottom) then you need to create a class that derives from Component.  Which is a very different kind of animal, it cannot have a visual representation on the form.  It certainly can't resemble anything like a panel.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680806/17034) for an example.

Comment: this is the case when i derivate it from component.Now i struggle to make it work like a panel. Shame C# don't support multiple derives :Component,Panel. 
I can't find any good info,instructions on net how to do it.
What i need to implement to draw in design mode my component ?

Comment: and I see it in my toolbox,just when i add it on form i need to see icon below designer of current instance of added component.(If is shrinked then i can't see it,that's why i need icon below,so i don't have to search it manually)

Comment: Sorry, you fatally misunderstand the difference between components and controls.  Not really sure how to lift you past that mental block, it ought to be obvious that "on the bottom" is not the same as "in the form".  A year from now you'll *totally* get it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late but I was just reading through same questions and this one caught my interest. I assume here what you are trying to do is have a Control on your Form that you can shrink in the Designer. As a result this will make the Control disappear from the Form. By having a Component below the Form you can still edit its Properties by selecting the Component.

My thought was trying a ControlDesigner. I'm not sure if this will work and it's not a trivial solution and I don't have time at the moment to work on it but there are two ways you could go here.

One: ControlDesiger will let you Shadow Properties so when you set them in the Designer they have no effect, this is why Controls that you set to invisible stay visible in the Designer. A Shadowed Property will have no effect or will have the effect you provide but will then update the actual Property when Serialized.

Two: You may actually be able to dynamically create a Component in the Control Designer and add it to the Form when you add your Panel derived Control. Then when you set a Property in your Component this change can be mirrored in your Control. I did something similar a few years ago just for something to waste time but I didn't spend a lot of time actually getting it to work right, so may not happen.

Just some thoughts

dannyhut